# Linking a GPO to a user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

I have written a code that allows me to link a GPO to an OU, but I want to be more specific and link it to a known user.

Below is the code that I've written:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module GroupPolicy
$GPOName = 'DisableInternet'
$GPO = New-GPO -Name $GPOName -Domain 'Administrateur.6NLG-AD'
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions' -ValueName 'NoBrowserOptions' -Value 1 -Type DWord -Action Create
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions' -ValueName 'NoBrowserOptions' -Value 1 -Type DWord -Action Update
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -ValueName ProxyServer -Value 0.0.0.0:80 -Type String -Action Create
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -ValueName ProxyEnable -Value 1 -Type DWord -Action Create
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -ValueName ProxyServer -Value 0.0.0.0:80 -Type String -Action Update
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Context User -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -ValueName ProxyEnable -Value 1 -Type DWord -Action Update
New-GPLink -Name $GPOName -Target 'OU=Nouvelle_UO,DC=Administrateur,DC=6NLG-AD'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't link a GPO to a user, only an OU. You can however filter the GPO using permissions, so it only applies to specific user or group.

So use `New-GPLink` to link the GPO to an OU that the user account resides in. Or at a level that inheritence will allow the GPO to apply to the users OU.

You'll need to remove `Authenticated Users` or any other wide-reaching groups like `Domain Users` from the GPO.

You can check for these groups by looking at the GPO, for example in the screenshot below, you can see under the **Security Filtering** section, that the default `Authenticated Users` has permissions to the GPO:

[image]

You will need to remove this group from the Security Filtering before adding permissions for your user:

```
Set-GPPermission -TargetName "Domain\Authenticated Users" -TargetType Group -PermissionLevel None -Replace
```

Then set the permissions of the GPO to the user you want it to apply to:

```
Set-GPPermission -Name DisableInternet -TargetName SamAccountName -TargetType User -PermissionLevel GpoApply
```

See [Set-GPPermission documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/set-gppermission) for further information and examples

Comment: thanks but I did not quite understand how to remove Domain Users  or any other wide-reaching groups from the GPO

Comment: I've updated my answer with better explanation on that :)